# Does Cross Product Makes Rank-1 Tensor??

Tags: vectors, tensors, cross-product

The problem itself is very simple. I have to prove that the cross product of two vectors, $C=A \times B$, satisfies vector transformation and thus rank-1 tensor. In other words, I have to prove that

$C'_i = \lambda_{ij} C_j$

where

$C_j=\varepsilon_{jmn}A_mB_n$

and

$C_i'=\varepsilon_{ikl}A_k'B_l'=\varepsilon_{ikl}(\lambda_{km}A_m)(\lambda_{ln}B_n)$

I can clearly see that this statement is true when I draw the diagram of each vector $C, C', A, B, A', B'$, but failed to prove it with algebra. I've tried putting 1, 2, 3 into each index, and failed with miserably long lines. Also tried to alter $i, k, l$ into $j,m,n$ as follows. I think this one is the most probable trial.

$\varepsilon_{ikl}\lambda_{km}\lambda_{ln}=
\varepsilon_{jmn}\lambda_{mm}\lambda_{nn}+\varepsilon_{jnm}\lambda_{nm}\lambda_{mn}+
\varepsilon_{mjn}\lambda_{jm}\lambda_{nn}+\varepsilon_{mnj}\lambda_{nm}\lambda_{jn}+
\varepsilon_{nmj}\lambda_{mm}\lambda_{jn}+\varepsilon_{njm}\lambda_{jm}\lambda_{mn}
$

which simplifies to

$\varepsilon_{ikl}\lambda_{km}\lambda_{ln}=\varepsilon_{jmn}
(\lambda_{mm}\lambda_{nn}-\lambda_{nm}\lambda_{mn}
-\lambda_{jm}\lambda_{nn}+\lambda_{nm}\lambda_{jn}
-\lambda_{mm}\lambda_{jn}+\lambda_{jm}\lambda_{mn})$

I expected this to be something like $\varepsilon_{jmn}(\lambda_{jj}+\lambda_{mj}+\lambda_{nj})$so that

$C_i'=\varepsilon_{ikl}A_k'B_l'=\varepsilon_{jmn}(\lambda_{jj}+\lambda_{mj}+\lambda_{nj})A_mB_n=
\varepsilon_{jmn}\lambda_{ij}A_mB_n$ But I always fail to convert $\lambda_{km}\lambda_{ln}$ into $\lambda_{ij}$.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: since the cross product is a bilinear transformation then it is a rank two tensor, and it is vector valued

Comment: The cross-product is often called a *pseudovector* exactly because it doesn't behave quite like a vector should.

Comment: Oh my...so they are basically not a vector. But thanks! I'll seek for pseudovectors and bilinear transformation from my textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a coordinate free formulation, you have the cross product defined as
$$
\forall v\in\Bbb R^3:\langle a\times b,v\rangle=\det(a,b,v)
$$
Applying a coordinate transformation $\Lambda$ then has the effect that
$$
⟨Λa×Λb,Λv⟩=\det(Λa,Λb,Λv)=\det(Λ)·\det(a,b,v)=\det(Λ)·⟨a×b,v⟩
$$
Consequently
$$
\det(Λ)(a×b)=Λ^T(Λa×Λb)
$$
This only simplifies to the usual formula if $Λ$ is a special orthogonal transformation, $\det(Λ)=1$ and $Λ^T=Λ^{-1}$. So if you want to reconstruct that with the explicit coordinates, you have to use these relations somewhere.

Note that $\det(Λ)Λ^{-T}$ is the co-factor matrix of $Λ$.

Comment: Thank you! I have picked mirror transformation as Λ with det(Λ)=-1 and proved that C cannot be consistent! I'll have to see if this satisfies the goal of the problem, but I think it satisfied my mind.